# Updating document with mongoose -- one property not being updated?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following code that updates a document in MongoDB:

```
exercisesRouter.put('/:exerciseId', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://nalanart:password@cluster0.2iplh.mongodb.net/workout-app-db?retryWrites=true&w=majority', 
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

    await Exercise.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.exerciseId, {
      name: req.body.name,
      sessionOne: req.body.sessionOne,
      sessionTwo: req.body.sessionTwo,
      weight: req.body.weight,
      failCount: req.body.failCount,
      reps: req.body.reps
    })

    res.sendStatus(204)

  } catch(error) {
    throw error
  }
})
```

The problem is that when I use Postman to test it, it updates everything correctly, except the 'reps' property. Here is the JSON body that I put into Postman:

```
{
    "name": "deadlift",
    "sessionOne": {
        "setsRegular": 4,
        "repsRegular": 5,
        "setsAmrap": 1,
        "repsAmrap": 5
    },
    "sessionTwo": {
        "setsRegular": 0,
        "repsRegular": 0,
        "setsAmrap": 0,
        "repsAmrap": 0
    },
    "weight": 145,
    "failCount": 2,
    "reps": [5, 5, 5, 4, 4]
}
```

This picture shows the document after making the put request (notice reps, which was previously [5, 5, 5, 5, 5] was not updated to [5, 5, 5, 4, 4]

[image: MongoDB document after put request]

I'm genuinely so confused by this, I feel like it's a small typo in my code that I must have overlooked or possibly something to do with it being an array? Any help is appreciated

Comment: maybe [...req.body.reps]

Comment: Can you try `console.log`ging the request body and post it as well?

Comment: This is what console.log on the req.body gives: {
  name: 'deadlift',
  sessionOne: { setsRegular: 4, repsRegular: 5, setsAmrap: 1, repsAmrap: 5 },
  sessionTwo: { setsRegular: 0, repsRegular: 0, setsAmrap: 0, repsAmrap: 0 },
  weight: 145,
  failCount: 2,
  reps: [ 5, 5, 5, 4, 4 ]
}

Comment: @OrAssayag just tried [...req.body.reps] does not work either :(

Comment: turns out it's because reps wasn't defined in my schema